# Entity Framework - Using Statement w/ Deferred Execution in a Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a simple repository class that is returning a list of Projects:

```
public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Project> GetProjects() 
    {
        DbEntities db = new DbEntities();

        return db.Projects;
    }
}
```

I have some code later down the line that is working off this IQueryable to do some sorting/paging:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var projectList = (from p in projectRepository.GetProjects()
                      orderby p.Name
                      select p).Take(20);

    return View(projectList.ToList());
}
```

I originally wrapped my GetProjects() call in a using statement out of habit - since it's usually a good idea to dispose your objects as soon as possible. This caused problems understandably because I was doing some further database work in my controller action.

Is it okay to just let the object be disposed when it is garbage collector? Is there a better way to do this instead? Should I be creating more targeted repository methods like:

```
public IQueryable<Project> GetProjects(int takeThisMany)
{
    return (from p in db.Projects
           orderby p.Name
           select p).Take(takeThisMany);
}
```

Is it a good or bad practice to return IQueryable objects that will be executed at a later time in a controller action without disposing the original context or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to return `IQueryable<T>`, but wrong to either not dispose an `ObjectContext` (you should always dispose any `IDisposable`) or to dispose it before the request is complete.

[Use constructor injection to pass the context to the repository and dispose it at the end of the request.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750557/how-do-you-centralize-the-entity-framework-data-context-in-a-web-application/6750579#6750579)

Comment: Seems like a good approach. I haven't really done a whole lot of DI...need to decide which library to use. What would you recommend for someone who has never really done DI before?

Comment: I'd recommend Mark Seeman's book "Dependency Injection in .NET". That said, any DI framework with MVC support will be easy to use for this. You can't go too far wrong.

Comment: So when you are doing constructor injection passing in the context, your repositories will be locally scoped to whatever action method you have more than likely? Before I had the repository as an instance variable of the Controller, but I don't think that would work if I need to dispose after I call an action right?

Comment: Anything which needs to be disposed will be disposed by the DI container at the end of the request, as log as you specify request scoping for the instance when configuring the container.

Comment: I've looked at two or three different tutorials for doing DI and none of them have talked about request scoping. Could you elaborate on this or provide an example?

Comment: I showed an example for autofac in the linked question (`InstancePerHttpRequest()`). @Alex Ford showed an example for NInject in the comments to my answer.